# Handoff for custom Apps

Tags: ios8

I am working on entertainment App, I have a query regarding iOS8 handoff feature. I have read about handoff that can be use for safari or other standard iOS Apps only. Is this applicable for custom Apps also?

Thanks,
Purushotham Jinka

Answer (score 0):

No that's not true.

You can handoff between a custom app on one device and the same custom app (or at least from the same developer) on another.

If you only have one app for iOS, you can even handoff between that app and Safari on another if your app experience can be continued on the web.

[More info](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/HandoffFundamentals/HandoffFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH3-SW1)